# How to find minutes?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Need help solving this real life problem, I have an SD Card of $4$GB(gigabyte), and a $32$ second video occupies $6.12$MB(megabyte), I need to know how many minutes or seconds can this $4$GB SD Card hold?

$4$GB=$4000$MB

I tried $4000$MB/$6.12$MB$=653.59$MB but couldn't figure it out seconds or minutes!

Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: Set up a proportion: 6.12 is to 4000 as 32 is to the number you want (in seconds).

Comment: $4000MB/6.12MB=653.59MB$: false, $4000MB/6.12MB=653.59$: true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 points, the first being units.

$\frac{4000MB}{6.12MB} = 653.59$, is a number with $\textbf{no}$ units, they cancel, in much the same way that $2 \text{ ft}$ is *twice* as long as $1 \text{ ft}$, as opposed to *"$2$ ft as long as $1$ ft"*, which is nonsensical here.

The second is exactly 2mkgz said. Let's argue through this in words to clarify.

$32$ seconds of video occupies 6.12 megabytes.  $6.12$ goes into $4000$  about $653.59$ times. Thus, we can get $653.59 \times 32$ seconds of video.

This is about $20915$ seconds (rounding to the nearest second), or $5$ hours, $48$ minutes, and 35 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{6.12\text{MB}}{32s}=\frac{4000\text{MB}}{x}$$
gives you
$$x=
\frac{4000\text{MB}}{6.12\text{MB}}\cdot 32s=
\frac{4000}{6.12}\cdot 32s=20915s.$$
Now
$$\left\lfloor\frac{20915}{60}\right\rfloor \text{ minutes} = 348 \text{ minutes}$$
and
$$20915s-(60\cdot348)s=35s.$$
$348$ minutes and $35$ seconds are actually $5$ hours, $48$ minutes and $35$ seconds.